# PHP utf8_encode with utf8 characters included

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

Background: 
A part of my system uses utf8_encode to convert html code to utf8 format before passing it on to json_encode.

Problem:
Everything was fine until I entered UTF8 characters(Chinese) into the system. I noticed that the mentioned UTF8 characters were encoded twice and came out garbled.

Sidenote:
I have no experience with charset encoding and whatnot until now. Perhaps I don't need to use utf8_encode before json_encode since my database and connections are already set to utf8. Without the Chinese characters in the html code, mb_detect_encoding would return ASCII(not ISO-8859-1). But I couldn't get through json_encode without returning null... thus the use of utf_8 encode which worked until now.

Update:
I finally solved the issue by typecasting the html code as string; via (string)$html; before assigning it to json_encode().

Thanks to all who posted here that led me to the final solution.

Comment: @x4rf41 Seems to be the case when the data used contains UTF-8 encoded characters. When not, it seems to be ISO-8859-1 encoding. Maybe you want to try [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) together with `mb_detect_encoding()`.

Comment: Have you tried `$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` ?

Comment: Read this: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Note to anyone stumbling across this question in the future: **do not think you can learn anything useful here.** This question and the answer are too vague and unclear to take any conclusions from, move on. If you don't yet understand encodings, this one page won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem. Maybe this would help: try to use `iconv();`. I had some problems with Polish characters (ąężćźłóń etc.)  in encodings other that utf8 - when I used `json_encode`, there was no output. Everything went just fine after using `iconv();`. The catch is, you have to know source encoding before you proceed. If you don't know encoding, use `mb_detect_encoding()` as @Lukas suggested. Example:

```
$content = iconv('ISO-8859-2','UTF-8', $content);
echo json_encode(array('content' => $content));
```

Comment: Actually I did try iconv() & mb_detect_encoding() previously. The result of mb_detect_encoding() was utf8, so I never pursued using iconv any further.
But my breakthrough came with 
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($html),'UTF-8',$html)

.Strangely, iconv('UTF-8','UTF-8',$html) was the answer...

Comment: There is no alternative to *knowing* the encoding. "Detecting" the encoding is not reliably possible by definition, it's just an unreliable first-valid-choice algorithm.

Comment: @ephemeron That means your text is already in UTF-8 and you do not need any kind of encoding conversion at all!

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. But the result showed otherwise. It's a mystery to me.

Comment: I guess that while a part of the HTML code is Unicode, but the rest is still ASCII that needs to be encoded.

Comment: @ephemeron That makes no sense. What exactly happens when you do nothing? What is the text and what does `bin2hex($text)` show?

Comment: I'm not a encoding expert, but I ask myself - does it has anything to do with whole family of utf8 encodings? We used to think that there is only one utf8 format, but for example, when creating new PostgreSql database, you can choose from many utf8 variants. Maybe both OP texts were in utf8, but chinese part was in utf8_chinese_ci (or something similar?).

Comment: @ex3 There's only one UTF-8 **encoding**. What you're talking about are *collations*. Read up on the difference, for example [here](http://kunststube.net/frontback).

Comment: Update. After considering what deceze mentioned. I ran a few tests to determine the reason behind the weird behaviour. To cut the story short, the $html was actually an object with __toString( ) method. I was ignorant of this until I did a vardump(). Using the proper output() method, I was able to get the right output without utf8 encoding. The difference between the __toString() and the output() method was merely a (string) typecast. Perhaps I inadvertently typecasted it as string when I used iconv() previously, which was why it seemingly worked.